# How can I get erlang crash dump file?

Tags: erlang, crash-dumps

My program crashes during execution and it writes `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` on console. But there is no any generated files in current working directory.
The question is where can I find generated crash dump file?
I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 / Erlang R15B01

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Linux core dump and an Erlang crash dump are not the same thing. If you're getting a segmentation fault and can't locate the core dump, you need to check your OS configuration. Do "cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern" to see where Linux wants to write the core file, check that that directory actually exists and is writable by you, and of course also check that the ulimit is set to actually produce a dump.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this, it is helpful in most cases

http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/observer/crashdump_ug.html

You can also look into http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/crash_dump.html which I don't recommend and I look at it as last solution.